# Replace root folder of writing paths used in process

Tags: disk-usage, io, tmpfs

I have a process that creates and uses temporary files. When I run many instances of this process the disk throughput becomes a bottleneck. I know that I can use a temporary file system mounted in RAM, but I don't know how to force the process to use it and I don't have access to the source code of this program.

Is there a way to replace the real root of the filesystem used by the process with a new one, placed in RAM, but only for write operations?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: One option would be to run the whole process in a `chroot`-jail on a temporary FS. But you would need to know where to put the output data of the process. Otherwise: do you know how and where the temporary files of the process are created? Then just make sure this place is in a RAM-tmp-FS.

Comment: Welcome to the site. For the sake of completeness, could you edit your post to include information on what OS flavour and version you are using?